# Scala 3 macros: code splitting / lookup type/term by name

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

Suppose that you have some typeclass and Scala 3 macros to derive it's instances. Macro code is large and bulky, so you decide to split project into two modules - runtime (typeclass itself) and macro code (which isn't required on runtime).

**The problem:** to write `case class ... derives TypeClass` you need to have macros defined in *runtime* module. Compiler will call `TypeClass.derived[T]`, you can't override that. You need to delegate that derivation somehow, without statically linking to macro module.

**Possible solution**:

1. Define (in macro module):

   ```
   object DerivationMacros { 
     inline def derive[T]: TypeClass[T] = /* impl */
   }
   ```
2. Define (in runtime module):

   ```
   object TypeClass {
     def derived[T]: TypeClass[T] = #{ DerivationMacros.derive[T] }
   }

   trait TypeClass[T] { /* impl */ }
   ```

   With `#{ .. }` denoting imaginary construct that generates it's contents on runtime.

**The problem 2**: you can't produce ASTs with statically unknown types. At least I didn't found a method to lookup term/type by name. To make this `#{ .. }` construct work, you need to statically link runtime module to macro module, defeating whole benefit. You need a way to produce that code using manually crafted AST, so that direct dependencies will be avoided.

The question is: either how to do original code splitting task, or how to lookup terms by names?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in "possible solution" you have circular dependency: both "macro module" depends on "runtime module" and vice versa?

Comment: You can always do `trait DerivedTypeClass[A] extends TypeClass[A]` in macro module and put `inline def derive[A]: DerivedTypeClass = ${ ... }` in `DerivedTypeClass` companion. Macro would have to use look for `TypeClass`es when generating bigger things from smaller things, and user would use semiauto with `case class Foo(a: Int) derives DerivedTypeClass` - this would make it easy to separate "runtime" module from "macro" module at the cost of extra type for derivation.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, only in compile time. Runtime module will generate invocation of macro module, which will then be processed by macros and replaced with code that depends only on runtime parts. Since there is no way for macro invocations to remain in compiled code, no runtime dependency is created.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, this way application code will have direct runtime dependency on macro module (it will use traits from there) and you cannot exclude macro module after build.

Comment: You can also add `derived[A]` as extension method to `TypeClass.type` see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/acjm2kOvRHq9AW93iDdixA . This would require importing extension method BUT if macro module wouldn't output anything other than runtime module types, it could be added as compile-only dependency.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I completely forgot about extension methods for objects.